# Can you find a random variable from a list?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Using a graphics engine called Turtle, I created points at specific points (the first 2 numbers in the parenthesis) and but a picture there. I assigned each one a variable. Is there a way you can randomly generate to find one or multiple of these variables randomly?

```
 def numberpin():
    p1 = [pin(0,0,50)]
    p2 = [pin(50,50,50)]
    p3 = [pin(-50,50,50)]
    p4 = [pin(100,100,50)]
    p5 = [pin(-100,100,50)]
    p6 = [pin(150,150,50)]
    p7 = [pin(-150,150,50)]
    p8 = [pin(50,150,50)]
    p9 = [pin(-50,150,50)]
    p10 = [pin(0,100,50)]
```

Comment: Put the `point` objects into a list, then randomly select from the `list` object using `random` module

Comment: @Natch You used a and and a but together. Please make your question clearer.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
from random import choice

pin_dictionary = {
    'p1': pin(0, 0, 50),
    'p2': pin(50, 50, 50),
    'p3': pin(-50, 50, 50),
    'p4': pin(100, 100, 50),
    'p5': pin(-100, 100, 50),
    'p6': pin(150, 150, 50),
    'p7': pin(-150, 150, 50),
    'p8': pin(50, 150, 50),
    'p9': pin(-50, 150, 50),
    'p10': pin(0, 100, 50),
}

def random_pin():
    return pin_dictionary[choice(list(pin_dictionary))]
```

Comment: A list would be more appropriate, don't you think? The names are useless, Natch gave names because he's a beginner and maybe doesn't know about Python datastructures.